# Corda - How to track tokens moved between accounts

Tags: corda

First I will detail the scenario.

We have a Party A that creates accounts and shares those accounts with a Party B.

This Party B issues tokens to the accounts created in Party A.

I've create a MyCustomTokenType that extends of TokenType and is a FungibleToken, without any custom attributes.

Party A can make token transfers between these accounts, according to a business rule.

Party B issuance and Party A transfer are working correctly. After transfers, all tokens continue with the issuer Party B.

**Now we need to issue a report detailing these transfers, indicating the number of tokens transacted, from which account to which account and the date of the transfer.
How can I track these transfers?**

I don't know if I can create a custom "issuer" attribute in MyCustomTokenType, but from what I've read, TokenType can't change the value of an attribute.

I don't know if I need to change the type of the token to EvolvableTokenType and set an "issuer" attribute.

I don't really know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcos,

I published 2 articles on this matter:

- [Off-ledger](https://blog.b9lab.com/complementing-tokens-sdk-with-custom-reporting-e50df796a52d) tokens reporting.
- [On-ledger](https://blog.b9lab.com/elevating-tokens-sdk-with-on-ledger-custom-reporting-57174ba614ba) tokens reporting.

Please read both articles.